# 2007 Toyota Highlander GPS Navigation map no longer works

Tags: toyota, navigation, highlander, manifold-absolute-pressure-sensor, gps

My 2007 Toyota Highlander gets the message "External system is not connected" when I push the "map" button. All other feature work on the counsel except for the gps navigation.

I left the windows open one day, huge rain storm came through. Ever since the navigation stopped working over a year ago.

Any suggestions on how to fix the GPS Navigation?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Pretty vague question, so this is a pretty vague answer.

Having gotten wet, there could be nearly anything wrong. You are going to have to go thru the entire navigation system, component by component, to find the failure.

Not knowing the extent of the water damage makes it impossible for us to know where to start.

- If the storm was strong enough to blow water onto the dash and
  navigation unit, you have your work cut out for you.
- If it was not that strong, I would suggest starting where the most
  water was.

Sometimes the manufacturers mount components under seats. If that is the case in your vehicle, that would be a good place to start.